# How to find the right Shift for the SABR Model

Tags: sabr, sabr-model

I'm looking for the right approche to find the right Shift for the SABR Model.

Comment: What properties would the "right shift" have?

Comment: hmm, @AlexC maybe that is the a core part of the question.

Comment: Well I guess we will never know ..